# how to parse arrays with direct values, twice json encoded

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

How can i parse an array with direct values , twice json encoded in Java, i get the data as a string and i want to get each value from the multidimensional array.

I'm kind of a noob regarding java, i managed to pull a not so elegant solution that encounters problems when i split by "," if the text inside has "," i could do it with regex but there must be a more elegant solution than this:

```
    content = the data fetched from the api as a string
content = content.replace("\"[[", "[");
            content = content.replace("]]\"", "]");
            content = content.replaceAll("\\\\","");
             for (String FaData : content.split("\\],\\[")) {
                for (String FaDataData : FaData.split(",")) {
                    FaDataData.toString();
                }
            }
```

Here you have an example of how content string actually looks like when is fetched:

```
"[[308576,1410880665,162506,\"Bobcat\",1,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i460\\\/308576.jpg\",\"Well no\",82,3,\"\"],[308592,1410883832,9479,\"undeathkiller\",2,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i\\\/308592.gif\",\"Guess the stupidity level\",89,9,\"\"],[308574,1410879991,32277,\"rady123lol\",2,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i\\\/308574.gif\",\"force of habit\",92,3,\"\"],[308624,1410897686,149704,\"Raptide7\",1,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i460\\\/308624.jpg\",\"*breathing intensifies*\",114,8,\"\"],[308648,1410911037,114669,\"Huller\",1,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i460\\\/308648.jpg\",\"SPOILERS: Stannis kills Dumbledore\",133,2,\"\"],[308628,1410898654,135315,\"Mig_L\",1,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i460\\\/308628.jpg\",\"So badass\",117,2,\"gold\"],[308639,1410902872,62886,\"burningowl\",1,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i460\\\/308639.jpg\",\"Kid's going places yo\",125,4,\"\"],[308520,1410858123,73400,\"koppie888\",1,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i460\\\/308520.jpg\",\"4chan, what a beautifull place\",99,7,\"\"],[308546,1410872801,32277,\"rady123lol\",1,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i460\\\/308546.jpg\",\"( \\u0361\\u00b0 \\u035c\\u0296 \\u0361\\u00b0)\",118,17,\"\"],[308486,1410846601,176339,\"AtLeastISubmit\",1,\"http:\\\/\\\/hugelolcdn.com\\\/i460\\\/308486.jpg\",\"That 70's show called it.\",101,3,\"\"]]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have your text in a String variable called **everything**, using the [JSONSimple package](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/), you can use the following code:

```
try {
    // create a new JSONParser
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    // first JSON decoding
    Object obj = parser.parse(everything);
    // second JSON decoding
    obj = parser.parse(obj.toString());
    // cast the parsed JSON string to a new JSONArray
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj;
    // loop through each line of the initial JSONArray
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
        // write the array values as a single line
        System.out.println(i + " : " + array.get(i));
        // parsing each line as a new JSONArray
        JSONArray tmp = (JSONArray)parser.parse(array.get(i).toString());
        for (int j = 0; j < tmp.size(); j++){ // iterate over the parsed values
            System.out.println(i+"."+j+" : "+tmp.get(j));
        }
    }
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Test1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Of course, you also have to import the following classes from the JSON package :

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
content = content.trim();
content = content.substring(0, content.length()); //gets the length of content string
content = content.replaceAll("\\/","/"); //Replaces all \/ to /
```

It would apply to the brackets as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JSON then I would suggest using a JSON library such as [jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String[][] 2Darray = mapper.readValue(content, String[][].class);
```

But then, if you are using JSON it would be nice if the format of your data was more structured. Obviously, that depends on whether or not you have any control over the API.